# Calling a javascript function inside a prototype modal window

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, modal-dialog

I am calling a prototype modal window on an onclick event.The page which is called inside the modal window contains a javascript function. This function is not executed inside the modal window. However, it works fine when the page is run individually and not inside the modal window.

My query is if javascript/Ajax function works inside prototype modal window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure how you load your window content (or what kind of modal window you are using), however `Ajax.Updater` has an option called `evalScripts` which needs to be set to true in order to evaluate the scripts from the request:

```
new Ajax.Updater(elementId, url, {evalScripts: true});
```

Comment: on click i am calling a function, openmodal_window(){ open DHTMLWindow(" ",'checkemail.php' ,420,320,"email");}, checkemail.php page contains a javascript function to validate the email. This function is not executed inside the modal window(prototype.js).

Comment: can you post your code ? what library are you using for the modal window ?

Comment: i am using prototype.js library which makes use of Dialog.info to create a modal window.

Comment: I have seen you use prototype, but I'm not sure about the modal window script (prototype doesn't include a modal window class, so you must be using a 3rd party library based on prototype). Can you post a link to the library ?

Comment: Seems this library is using Ajax.Request which doesn't support `evalScript` . I would try loading the content using Ajax.Updater into a hidden div, and then opening that div in the modal window.

Comment: i am using Ajax.Updater and using an hidden div, still its not working.

Comment: make sure to put `evalScripts: true` in the Ajax.Updater options